# How to make a search match even though the searched string isn't exact in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am used to work with Postgres. With postgres I was able to make a more "intelligent search" by installing [the pg_trgm trigram extension](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/pgtrgm.html) and then the user could miss a letter like  "aple" or position the letters wrong "appel" that the search would match. With Mysql I don't know which feature to use.  I can someone give a direction?

My query is like this:

```
   select *,
   case when titulo like '%pneu%' then 1 else 0  end as rank_titulo,
    case when descricao like '%pneu%' then 1 else 0  end as  rank_descricao,
  case when tag like '%pneu%' then 1 else 0 end as rank_tag
   from produto where  titulo like '%pneu%'
   or descricao like '%pneu%' or 
  tag like '%pneu%' order by rank_titulo desc, rank_descricao desc, 
   rank_tag desc   ;
```

I don't care if the user typed "pineu", "pneo", "penu" that search should match.

I don't want a working code that solve my problem, I just want to know the feature that I should use, some demo code would be appreciated.

Comment: you might be looking for SOUNDS LIKE or soundex() I think.

Comment: @ADyson That's not going to work for me as I am not using brazilian portuguese.

Comment: What precisely was the feature you used in postgres? If you tell us what it is called and where to find the docs it would be much easier to see what a direct equivalent (if any) might be.

Comment: I used pg_trgm postgres extension.

Comment: I found a function: https://www.lucidar.me/en/web-dev/levenshtein-distance-in-mysql/ it works well but I don't know how to modify it to work with substrings. So it's no use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nearest MySQL feature to postgreSQL's trigram extension is [FULLTEXT searching](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-search.html).

You might use this syntax.

```
...WHERE MATCH(titulo, descricao, tag) AGAINST('pneu' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)...
```

You need a FULLTEXT index in your table to make this work.

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ft ON produto(titulo, descricao, tag);
```

Beware a couple of things: FULLTEXT only works on words of three letters or more by default, and natural language mode works strangely on small tables. You can change these things. You may also need to add [stopwords](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-stopwords.html) in your language (Portuguese?).

Also beware that it often works counterintuitively. You may find yourself asking "why did it do that?" quite often.